# Daughter requires a transit visa through India

Tags: visas, transit, india, bom

My daughter (dual English / South African citizenship) has traveled through India and is currently in Sri Lanka. She is flying to visit  me in the USA on the 12th of December. She has to fly from Colombo to Mumbai and then on to the USA. She had a single entry tourist visa for her travels through India.

My question is, will she be able to get a transit visa to fly out of Mumbai (I know there is a 2 month lapse before you can reapply for a tourist visa in India again) and how does she get it whilst travelling in Sri Lanka?

Comment: Which nationality is your daughter?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7650/how-to-transit-through-delhi-without-a-visa

Comment: She has dual English / South African citizenship.

Comment: As per the OP, the daughter has a English and South African citizenship.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer Michael Hampton - I appreciate this and it verifies what we found out at the Indian High Commission in Colombo. Thanks again!

Comment: If you qualify (which I think she does) it's silly to get any India tourist visa other than the 5-year multiple-entry one. It saves so much trouble just being able to freely enter/transit without worrying about re-applying.

Answer (score 5):

Your daughter will *not* need a visa to transit at Mumbai if she remains airside; she would just [take the lift to the departures area](http://www.csia.in/passenger/faqs.aspx) after going through security. This will happen if the flights are on a single booking. If the flights are booked separately, and the luggage not checked through, she may need to collect her luggage and check it in again, which may require passing through immigration/customs. In this case she would need a transit visa.

Note that [for South African citizens the transit visa far cheaper than for UK citizens](http://in.vfsglobal.co.uk/transit_fees.html) due to a special arrangement between India and South Africa. So if she does need to transit India landside and get the transit visa, it would probably be better to do it on the SA passport.

She can apply for the transit visa at the High Commission of India in Colombo, but should do so as soon as possible as the application will take longer than for a Sri Lanka citizen. The [embassy web site](http://www.hcicolombo.org/page/display/20) says: "Minimum of 5-6 working days."

Obviously it would be more convenient to ensure that the flights are on a single booking so that she can remain and transit airside and not require a visa at all.