# Layover via Delhi airport, will I need an Indian visa to transfer flight?

Tags: visas, transit, india, transit-visas, del

Just a quick question regarding my upcoming flight from London Heathrow to Kathmandu, Nepal.

I am flying via Delhi with a 3 hour layover and Jet Airways is the operator for the entire flight. Normally, with transfer flights you **DO NOT** have to pay for a visa for the country you are connecting in, **unless you leave the airport**. However, a colleague of mine who has previously worked a lot in Nepal said that they have often had to buy an Indian visa in order to reach their connecting flight to Nepal. I do not believe this is the case but, having never done the journey before, I have no idea!

Has anyone got any experience of this flight? Or visa situation?

**EDIT**

```
LHR > DEL (Depart from Terminal 4 and Arrive into Terminal 3)

DEL > KTM (Depart from Terminal 3)
```

*[The same terminals are used on the return flight]*

**EDIT 2**

British passport holder

Comment: You need to find out what terminals the flights are arriving and departing from. It would be best to check with the airline directly.

Comment: Hi @BurhanKhalid, thanks for your reply - I have added the terminals I am flying into but I think you're right, maybe contacting the airline is best. I just wanted to avoid the call cost to India!

Comment: Whether you need a visa depends on your nationality, not on the airline you're travelling with. Since you've not told us your nationality, we don't know if you need a visa or not.

Comment: Related but not possibly a dup http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7650/how-to-transit-through-delhi-without-a-visa

Comment: @RedBaron IMO it is a dupe

Comment: It's **irrelevant** what terminals you arrive/depart from. The question is: is the ticket in one booking? If yes, you do not need a visa, otherwise you do

Comment: Thanks for your reponses - I'll read the possible dupe answer. All flights were made under one booking! So thank you @Crazydre

Comment: @TaylorDay You're welcome. Added an answer with an official source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the trip is in one booking, you do **not** need a visa.

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=gb&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=in&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of confirmed onward tickets
>   for a max. transit time of 24 hours

Comment: Onward tickets can be in their own, separate bookings; and that too will not change this requirement of visa.

Comment: @DavChana This is not the case in practice - check-in clerks will generally deny boarding if the connecting flight in not on the same ticket and you don't have a required visa. And almost certainly if you have checked-in luggage

Comment: Ok, but I have travelled DOH->IST->CDG with checked-in, with Peagues on DOH->IST, & AtlasG on IST->CDG,(CDG Visa) with ~6 Hours of Stay at IST, no visa (I need visa to enter Turkey). yes, the check-in agent objected, but when I showed him Timatic Text (same as above), he checked with supervisor, & allowed me to board. & few more. I mean it does not say on Timatic that "bookings need to be same". It just asks "confirmed onward ticket of 24 hour or less transit"

Comment: @DavChana Correct, *de jure* any onward reservation is OK, but *de facto* it's likely to be a problem. And again, luggage, how did you organise that, or did you go hand luggage only? You **must** clear immigration in order to collect it. Nowadays they will **not** normally check through if it's on separate tickets