# Do I need a transit visa in New Delhi?

Tags: transit, india, afghan-citizens

I am an Afghan citizen. traveling from China to Afghanistan through New Delhi airport, with 2 different airlines with a layover of 10 hours. I don't have to claim luggage. Do I need a transit visa or not? can I get into my next flight to Afghanistan without having a transit visa or not please help by answering this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 2 different airlines on 2 different tickets or on the same ticket? If two different tickets (i.e. booked separately), it is likely that you will be denied boarding for your first flight (leaving PRC) as you do not have the paperwork necessary to enter your destination country as the airline sees it (India).

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7650/how-to-transit-through-delhi-without-a-visa

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't. There is a diversion for International transfers at the Delhi Airport right before the Immigration checkpoint. After landing, you'll enter the arrival level of the airport. From there, you can head towards International transfers and finally, from there, you can board your next flight on the departure level.